# Error en POM.xml al agregar libreria de JavaFX 18

Tags: java, javafx, librería

tengo el siguiente problema, agregue al proyecto las librerías de javaFX18, y al momento de intentar utilizarla en un proyecto que comencé sin estas librerías me arroja el siguiente error:
Cuando hago un cleand and build

```
The POM for unknown.binary:javafx-swt:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:javafx.base:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:javafx.controls:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:javafx.graphics:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:javafx.media:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:javafx.web:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

Todo lo demás lo carga correctamente. Debo modificar el POM para que tome la librería JavaFX18?
Este es el archivo POM, la verdad no se como editarlo, porque es la primera ves que intento agregar una librería a un proyecto ya comenzado. Estuve buscando como modificar el POM para cuando se implementa la librería javafx pero no he encontrado nada que me permita acomodar el archivo. Agradecería de su ayuda para poder solucionar este problema. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ConexionDataBase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swt</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.base</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>   etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pom para javafx 18.0.1

probado en netbeans 13
Debe indicar la clase principal en la etiqueta main class .
Sí necesita más dependencias puede indicarlo

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>clase principal aquí</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Gracias Giovanni anduvo ok.